# how to disable lwuit vkb and show default system vkb?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, virtual-keyboard

i tried the command

```
Display.getInstance().setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null);
```

it disabled luiwt virtual keyboard as well as the system virtual keyboard..

how to disable lwuit virtual keyboard and show platform built-in virtual keyboard.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that. Moreover, I'm pretty sure the only way to display and interact with the native virtual keyboard in a Java-Me midlet is with full-screen mode text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native VKB works by default for both Android & RIM devices.

It **can't** be supported on MIDP devices since the MIDP API's have no provisioning for VKB's. The only way to get it to work on Nokia devices (etc.) is to keep it constantly on through a jad property.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API docs for setDefaultVirtualKeyboard](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Display.html#setDefaultVirtualKeyboard%28com.sun.lwuit.impl.VirtualKeyboardInterface%29) `null` doesn't look like the right parameter for what you're trying to get.

Null parameter is intended to "disable the VirtualKeyboard" not to set it to something else. As for setting *built-in* keyboard, it looks like there's no API for that

Answer (score 0):

try this, how ever i have not tested

```
Display.getInstance().setShowVirtualKeyboard(false);
```